# Can't insert item in database using servlet

Tags: java, mysql, xml, jsp, servlets

I am trying to insert values into table of database using servlet and jsp and MySQL Workbench as database. When I fill in the form and submit, it shows only blank screen, no output is displayed and in the database values are not updated.These are the following details:

1) Controller.java

```
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        String dburl = getServletContext().getInitParameter("dburl");
        String dbuser = getServletContext().getInitParameter("dbuser");
        String dbpassword = getServletContext().getInitParameter("dbpassword");
        String dbdriver = getServletContext().getInitParameter("dbdriver");

        Connection conn = DAO.getConnectionJDBC(dburl, dbuser, dbpassword, dbdriver);

        String title = request.getParameter("title");
        String actor = request.getParameter("actor");
        String actress = request.getParameter("actress");
        String genre = request.getParameter("genre");
        String year = String.valueOf("year");

        String queryMessage = "INSERT INTO movies (title, actor, actress,genre,year)"
                + "values (" + title + ",'" + actor + "','" + actress + "','"
                + genre + "','" + year + "')";

        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        int result = statement.executeUpdate(queryMessage);
        conn.close();
        if (result > 0) {
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Added.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }

    }
}

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

2) DAO.java

```
public class DAO {

public static Connection getConnectionJDBC(String dburl, String dbuser,String dbpassword, String dbdriver) throws IOException {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(dbdriver);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
    }
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl,dbuser,dbpassword);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
    }

    if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("connection established");
    }
    return connection;
}
```

}

3) AddMovie.jsp

```
<form action="Controller" method="post">
code to insert in text box
</form>
```

4) web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myapp.controller.Controller</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Controller</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<context-param>
    <param-name>dbuser</param-name>
    <param-value>root</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>dbpassword</param-name>
    <param-value>root</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>dbdriver</param-name>
    <param-value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>dburl</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/moviedb</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Did u debug whether db update was sucessfull...why don't you catch the exceptions  ?....show us the code of added.jsp ?

Comment: <form>
<div id="header">
<h1>Welcome To Our Movie Store</h1>
</div>
    
    <div id="nav" >
    </div>
    
<div id="section">
    <center>
<br><br><b><font size="9">1 Movie Added Successfully</font></b><br><br>

<a href="index.html">Click here to go back to main page</a>
    </center>
</div></form>

Comment: You should probably put some println statements in or get a logger working so you can see if the controller is being called.